# Dancer2: fetching nested data from hash stored in YAML session

Tags: perl, session, dancer

I'm using Dancer2 and the YAML session engine. I stored a complete hash in a session with the following code:

```
post '/login' => sub {
    # ...
    my $userdata = {
        fname => 'John',
        lname => 'Doe',
        uid => 1234,
    };
    # ...
    session userdata => $userdata;
    # ...
}
```

The omitted code checks the login data against a database and returns that `$userdata` hashref.
This code creates a session file under $appdir/sessions with this content:

**session file**

```
userdata:
  fname: John
  lname: Doe
  uid: 1234
```

How can I retrieve single values from this session in my `app.pm` file?
It works great in the template files (*.tt) and `<% session.userdata.fname %>` yields `John`, as expected.
However, I want to fetch the first name in `app.pm`, like so:

```
get '/userdetails' => sub {
    my $firstname = session('userdata.fname'); # gives undef
    # do sth. with $firstname
}
```

Is that feasable? Or do I have to

```
my $userdata = session('userdata'); # fetch complete hash
# do sth. with $userdata->{fname}
```

I tried

- `session('userdata.fname')`
- `session('userdata/fname')`
- `session('userdata:fname')`
- `session('userdata fname')`
- RTFM (YAML's and Dancer2's)

but none of them worked and gave `undef`. The manuals and tutorials only fetch "first level values", not nested ones.

Comment: A bit unrelated: are you aware of the[ Dancer advent calendar](http://advent.perldancer.org/2016)? It's a bit hard to find because they still haven't linked it on the Dancer project homepage.

Comment: @simbabque Yes, thank you. During my research I more than once noticed that page but didn't pay the attention it deserves. I thought it was some lottery. My fault. It's actually a a collection of 20 (as of today) _Do's, Don'ts, and best practice_.

Comment: This year they are really high quality.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Template Toolkit syntax is completely independent of Perl Dancer2, and you should expect any form of addressing to carry over. The origin of the data as a YAML file is also irrelevant, as the Dancer session is just a Perl hash structure

<strike>The manual doesn't make it very clear, but</strike>

```
session('userdata')
```

is the same as

```
session->{userdata}
```

So you can use

```
session->{userdata}{fname}
```

to read the subsidiary fields

(Or possibly `session('username')->{fname}` if you prefer, but that looks a bit icky to me!)

*Note that you shouldn't use the YAML session engine in production code, as it's very slow*

Comment: Neither `session->{userdata}` nor `session->{userdata}{fname}` works (1st gives an empty hash, 2nd gives undef). But `session('userdata')->{fname}` works. But anyway, your answer helped a lot and I can now dig further.

Comment: I wanted to use YAML in production code because it's simple and [they say](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Dancer2/lib/Dancer2/Session/YAML.pm) it _"… can perfectly be used in production environments …"_ but I'm new to Dancer and still evaluating. I already have a session management (handcrafted CGI, Cookies, and MySQL) and want to switch to Dancer2. Perhaps I can marry them. I'll see.

Comment: @PerlDuck: My apologies. `session('name')` and `session->{var}` were identical in the original *Dancer*. I didn't think that would have changed.

Comment: The good thing about YAML is that it's human-readable, which makes it ideal for development. That's not necessarily something you need in production, unless it is. If your app is some internal tool and your users are notorious for breaking things, it might be useful. If you store a lot of objects in the session on the other hand and want stuff to be fast (those two are not related), it's probably less useful and a database or nosql solution might be a better approach. All the file sessions don't require additional dependencies, which can be another plus.

Comment: @Borodin Thank you. But only `session('userdata')->{fname}` works – `session->{userdata}{fname}` does not (it gave undef). I'm using Dancer2 0.204001 and Perl v5.22.1 if that helps.